# Object is not printed in the order it is defined in, in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print this the return of this function in the same order it is defined in:

```py
import numpy

def Decrypt_CRT_RSA(c, d, p, q):
    """
    Decrypts RSA with CRT
    :param c: The cipher text you want to decrypt
    :param d: The secret key
    :param p: A prime number forming half of the secret key
    :param q:A prime number forming the other half of the secret key
    """
    dp = d % (p - 1)
    dq = d % (q - 1)
    cp = c % p
    cq = c % q
    m0 = pow(cp, dp, p)
    m1 = pow(cq, dq, q)
    Msg = CRT([m0, m1], [p, q])[0]
    return {
        'p part of the cipher text: ' + str(cp),
        'q part of the cipher text: ' + str(cq),
        'p part of the private key: ' + str(dp),
        'q part of the private key: ' + str(dq),
        'first half of the message m: ' + str(m0),
        'second half of the message m: ' + str(m1),
        'the full message (aka m0 + m1): ' + str(Msg)
    }

c = 64649
d = 241187
p = 659
q = 673
print(Decrypt_CRT_RSA(c, d, p, q))
```

but it is printed like this:

> {'p part of the cipher text: 67', 'the full message (aka m0 + m1): 12345', 'first half of the message m: 483', 'q part of the private key: 611', 'second half of the message m: 231', 'p part of the private key: 359', 'q part of the cipher text: 41'}

And as you can see the second thing printed is the one starting with `the full message`  which is the one I return last. How do i get python to respect the return as defined by the function? Or even better, return in the same way it is defined (aka each entry on a new line)

Comment: ``{..., ..., ...}`` defines a set. Sets have arbitrary order. That's basically their point. Did you intend to define a dictionary, as in ``{'p part of the cipher text': cp, 'q part of the cipher text': cq, ...}`` (note the colon *outside* of the string literal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the return statement is returning a set, here the colons are inside strings, so try like this to return dict:

```
  return {
        'p part of the cipher text': str(cp),
```

And so on